# How to reduce Web analytics reporting DB size

Tags: central-administration, web-analytics

SharePoint 2010 web analytics reporting DB for our public facing site has grown over 30 GB over the last year.

We are using Google Analytics for analytics purposes and would like to retain only last 3 months of data in SharePoint web analytics.

If we now change "Data Retention Period" on the Web Analytics Service Application will it automatically delete the old data from analytics reporting DB? If not how can we reduce the size of this database? TIA